# Elastic-search how to order by group values alphabetically?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.6.0

I have bellow query to group result, what i want to add to this query is to sort grouped values alphabetically.

```
GET promote_kmp/audit_table/_search
{
  "aggs":{
    "group_by_table_name":{
       "terms":{
         "field":"table_name",
         "size":1000000000
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the [`order` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order):

```
POST promote_kmp/audit_table/_search
{
  "aggs":{
    "group_by_table_name":{
       "terms":{
         "field":"table_name",
         "size":1000000000,
         "order": { "_term": "asc" }          <---- add this
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
GET promote_kmp/audit_table/_search
{
  "aggs":{
     "group_by_table_name":{
        "terms":{
           "field":"table_name",
           "size":1000000000,
           "order": {
             "_term": "asc"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```